# "... was not yet done" vs "... was not done yet": what is the correct order?

Tags: grammar, style

***Note**: This might very well be a duplicate but I don't know the correct and more general grammar terms. So I only searched for the words in my specific example but did not find an answer. Do not hesitate to close and point me to a more general resource if one exists already.*

---

This is the exact sentence I wrote (you can read it [from source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673918/9401096) if more context is needed)

> In that case, just add a default value to prevent an error if API was not `yet` called

I'm wondering about the order of the word `yet` in that sentence and if it should be

> In that case, just add a default value to prevent an error if API was not called `yet`

I'm also open to criticism if the above should be turned totally differently.

---

*Funny fact*: while editing to fix a typo I realized I have the exact same type of grammatical construction in my above opening note, which I still don't know how to describe in intelligible English and where I still wonder what the correct order is:

> ... a more general resource if one exists `already`.

vs

> ... a more general resource if one `already` exists.

Comment: I suspect this is more a matter of style than of grammar.

Comment: @mdewey Should I understand that both are actually correct?

Comment: Yes, all four versions are correct and natural.